# Python: Input Validation

Tags: python, validation

I'm asking the user if they want to go first or not and use input validation so that only "y" "Y" "n" or "N" are accepted as a valid response. my code seems to crash when i run it.

```
choice = raw_input("Would you like to go first or not? (y/Y or n/N): ")
print ""

try:
    valid_choice = False
    while not valid_choice:
        if choice == "y" or choice == "Y":
            users_turn = True
            valid_choice = True
        elif choice == "n" or choice == "N":
            users_turn = False
            valid_choice = True
            break
    else:
            print "Invalid Choice."

except NameError:
    print "You can only enter y/Y or n/N"
```

Comment: *"my code seems to crash"* -- In what way, more precisely? What's the error?

Comment: you are missing `break` in if clause

Comment: If any of these answers helped you, you should select one as a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Ahm, the flow in your code has a bit too many possible paths. You could simplify it with something like:

```
question = "Would you like to go first or not? (y/Y or n/N): "
choice = raw_input(question)
while choice not in ['y', 'Y', 'n', 'N']:
    print 'Invalid choice'
    choice = raw_input(question)
users_turn = choice in ['y', 'Y']
```

Having said that, I should say that it is a common pattern for a console application to use `(Y/n)` to indicate that it accepts the letters `y` or `n` as responses (in both lower and upper cases), but the upper case indicates the default option.

So, if you can trust the user to make a decision the first time you ask for an input to the question, you can set a default response and code it like this:

```
choice = raw_input('Would you like to go first? (Y/n)')
users_turn = choice.lower() not in ['n', 'no']
```

Comment: @zhangxaochen I saw your edit to use a string, but I think I still prefer using a list -- that way you can add other possible answers  likes `'yes', 'no'` and initials to support other languages.

Comment: yes and I removed that edit also because `'Yn' in 'yYnN'` gives `True`. sorry ;P

Comment: @zhangxaochen oh yeah, there's also that! =)

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative to elias' answer, I'd like to present the following:

```
while True:
    choice = raw_input("Would you like to go first or not? (y/Y or n/N): ")
    if choice in ["y", "Y", "n", "N"]:
        break
    print "Invalid choice"
users_turn = choice in ["y", "Y"]
```

It's better in that it doesn't duplicate the ask line, but worse in that the `while True`/`break` syntax is a bit ugly (it would be nice if Python had `do`...`while` like C, but alas). Choose for yourself which you like the most. :)

Also, just to point out some of the several errors you have in your own code:

- The `try`...`except NameError` block is completely redundant, since nothing in your code will throw `NameError`, and especially not to signal an actual user error.
- You have your `else` line at the wrong indentation. As it stands, it matches the `while` block rather than `if`/`elif` block, causing behavior you most likely do not intend.
- The `break` in the `elif` block is redundant, since the `while` loop will exit anyway when you've set `valid_choice` to `True`.
- **Most important of all**, you don't reask the user when he types an invalid answer, causing your code to loop forever. Perhaps this is the unspecified crash you speak of?

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_one_of(prompt, options, default=None):
    options = set(options)
    while True:
        val = raw_input(prompt)
        if val == '' and default is not None:
            return default
        elif val in options:
            return val

response = get_one_of('Do you want to go first? [Yn] ', 'yYnN', 'y')
users_turn = response in 'yY'
```